# OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker not responding with iPod Touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, ipod-touch

**A little background:**

I am working on an iOS app which does audio recording and makes use of the audio session category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.  The app also plays sound effects which I want to play through the device's main speaker (while the user is not recording).  In order stop output audio from playing through the main speakers while recording I use the following code snippet:

```
UInt32 defaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                        sizeof (defaultRoute),
                        &defaultRoute);
```

When the user starts recording I run the same code again with a `defaultRoute` of `0` which causes output audio to stop being played through the speakers and therefore not included in the recording.  This method has been working fine on the iPhone.

**The Issue:**

When I run the same code on an iPod Touch (4th generation), the `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` property does not seem to have any affect. The result is that while a user is recording audio on their iPod Touch, sound effects will still play through the speaker and are included in the recording.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to fix it?  I want to the behaviour on the iPod Touch to match the behaviour on the iPhone: output audio does not play through the main speakers while recording.

**Note:**

The closest to a solution that I have gotten is detecting if the device is an iPod Touch and if it is, mute system audio when recording starts using the following code snippet:

```
[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].volume = 0.0;
```

This was not a desirable solution as when this code is executed, the volume overlay view pops up showing that the volume was turned down.  This adds confusion to the UI and is not a good enough solution.

Any help would be appreciated!